# sync_binlog is different for master and slave

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqlbinlog

Is it fine if sync_binlog is different for master and slave. For my system I can see master has sync_binlog=1 and slave has sync_binlog=0

Answer (score 0):

It's totally fine.

`sync_binlog` only has an impact on the server where it's configured.

A value of 0 offers higher performance in exchange for reduced resiliency against a loss of binlog entries in the event of a crash.

As such, 0 is common on a replica and 1 is common on a master.